# In ARC, dealloc method calls method/block that contains weak reference to self result in weakSelf = nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

As the title states, in ARC mode, when I define a block using self reference (weak to avoid reference cycle):

```
...
id __weak weakSelf = self;
self.someBlock = ^(){
    if (weakSelf != nil){
        (do something with weakSelf...)
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
};
...
```

In dealloc I call the block:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    ...
    BOOL isNil = self.someBlock();
    ...
}
```

Then I found isNil = YES.

When I want blocks in dealloc to do something with self, this seems to be a problem.

This also happen in callback functions, which I will not give an example here.

My solution is using __unsafe_unretained instead of __weak.

But this looks ugly.

Is there better ways to avoid nil weak self in dealloc?

**Updated Question:** Why `weakSelf` is niled even when `self` is not? Is it the reason of `dealloc`?

---

To make it clear, I paste the test code below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface blockWeak : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) BOOL (^someBlock)();
@property (nonatomic) int num;

- (void)makeBlock;

@end

@implementation blockWeak

- (void)makeBlock
{
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    self.someBlock = ^(){
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.num = 2;
        return weakSelf == nil?YES:NO;
    };
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    BOOL isNil = self.someBlock();
    if (isNil) {
        NSLog(@"weakSelf is nil.");
    }
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        blockWeak *bw = [[blockWeak alloc] init];
        bw.num = 1;
        [bw makeBlock];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the apparent error mentioned in the answer, what's your use case? Checking if `weakSelf` has been already nilled in `dealloc` doesn't seem to be something you should have to do.

Comment: The real use case is, I need the block to do some clean up job other than memory freeing in dealloc, which may use properties/ivars of the class or even self. I modify the question a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: you can call anything in dealloc, even using self.

Comment: I've tried that. Using self is OK. I copy the code on the block to dealloc and it works. But when you use blocks/functions that hold a weak pointer to self in dealloc, it doesn't work because when the program goes inside the block/function, "weakSelf" becomes nil. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works, and in my opinion is cleaner as no reference to `self` is then held.
Also there is no real need for the return `BOOL` of the block now, but I've left this in...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface blockWeak : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) BOOL (^someBlock)(blockWeak *);
@property (nonatomic) int num;

- (void)makeBlock;

@end

@implementation blockWeak

- (void)makeBlock
{
    self.someBlock = ^BOOL(blockWeak *object){
        object.num = 2;
        return object == nil?YES:NO;
    };
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"num = %d", _num);
    BOOL isNil = _someBlock(self);
    if (isNil) {
        NSLog(@"block returned NO");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"block returned YES");
    }
    NSLog(@"num = %d", _num);
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        blockWeak *bw = [[blockWeak alloc] init];
        bw.num = 1;
        [bw makeBlock];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
num = 1
block returned YES
num = 2
```

Comment: Using `self` as a parameter of `block` is a good way to postpone the reference of `self`. But I still wonder why `weakSelf` is niled in `dealloc`.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not call the block. That would be:

```
BOOL isNil = self.someBlock();
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Just forget about that